dotnet publish command takes too long to execute for a console application
I am working on two source code file (say, file A.cs and B.cs) console application, where file A has some common classes and a main method, which calls a method in file B. I have a basic .csproj file,
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I build this application using publish command to generaete a single file executable,
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained false -p:PublishSingleFile=true.
and then run the generated executable with required arguments.
./<generated-file> <list-of-arguments>

So, compilation takes a lot more time than expected, while execution is pretty fast. And while compiling with multiple concurrency compilation time increases a lot. How I can reduce the compilation time here?

How long does it take?

How long does publishing take with and without PublishSingleFile=true ? What does the console show? If I publish any of my large console applications right now, publishing will be fast, unless it has to pull a lot of new NuGet packages. We can't guess what's going on without any information

"compilation takes a lot more time than expected" - how much time did you expect and how long does it take? Is it in the realm of possibilities that your expectation could have been wrong?

Sorry for replying late, So the publish command takes around 15-20 secs for a single run, and when I run multiple threads its taking more than 30 secs and we have a 30s timeout for the threads who are waiting for the resources, therefore those threads sometime gives timeout error.
